# Structures and Pointers dereferencing question

Tags: c, pointers, structure

The pointer `MyStruct* ps` points to `&s`.
What is the value, if any, after de-referencing **only** `*ps` without accessing any struct members of `MyStruct`?

```c
#include    <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char c;
    int x;
    double d;
} MyStruct;

int main(void) {
    MyStruct s = {'a', 132, 456.789};
    MyStruct* ps = &s;
    
    printf("Member c has a value of %c\n",(*ps).c);
    printf("Member x has a value of %d\n", (*ps).x);
    printf("Member d has a value of %f\n", (*ps).d);    

    /* printf("Here i want to print the outcome of\n", *ps); */
}
```

EDIT: I finally got the solution! And i know what its containing as value. It's the char 'a'. With `printf("%c\n", *ps` i got the value inside of `*ps`. I know i get a warning but still i know now what it contains. Also the comments and other answers were really helpful!

Comment: the beginning of the memory block which holds the struct (in this case 's').

Comment: Wow, that was my first conclusion. So a struct type is working/same as an array?

Comment: "So a struct type is working/same as an array?" No, it's not. An array is a collection of homogeneous data, each element is of the same type and  of the same size. A structure can contain heterogeneous "elements" where the type and size of each "element" can be different (and more importantly, the compiler might add *padding* between structure members).

Comment: The value of `*ptr` is `s`, which is a `MyStruct`. The function `printf` knows how to print a `char`, or an `int`, or a `float`, but it does not know how to print a `MyStruct`.

Comment: Alright ty for all your input in this insane speed! love this site :D *bookmarked*

Comment: nit.  It is not correct to say that `ps points to &s`.  `ps` points to `s`, and the value of `ps` is `&s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition

```
MyStruct s = {'a', 132, 456.789};
```

creates a block in memory looking something like

```
+---+
| c |
+---+
| x |
+---+
| d |
+---+
```

Then the definition

```
MyStruct* ps = &s;
```

modifies it to something like this:

```
+----+     +---+
| ps | --> | c |
+----+     +---+
           | x |
           +---+
           | d |
           +---+
```

The "value" of `ps` is the address of the first member of the `s` structure object.

Comment: so to print `*ps` i've to do write following: `printf("%c\n", *ps);` ?
EDIT: got an error cuz `*ps`is of type `MyStruct`

Comment: The type of `*ps` is wrong for the `%c` format. The type of `*ps` is `MyStruct`. If you have e.g. `char *pc = &s.c;` then you have two pointers (`ps` and `pc`) pointing to the same address but they have different types.

Comment: The question was about "what does `*ps` represent" rather than "what does `ps` represent".  You're clear about the latter; you don't clearly address the former.

Answer (score 1):

`*ps` denotes the entire structure. The “value” of `*ps` is an aggregate with the values of all its members. The C standard does not provide any way to print it, but you can assign it to another structure of the same type, pass it to a function that accepts an argument of that type, and return it from a function that has a return type of that type. Effectively, `*ps` is the same as `s`.

Answer (score -1):

one way to think of it is that

```
 MyStruct* ps;
```

is the same as

```
 MyStruct *ps;
```

Which says: '*ps' is a 'MyStruct'